# Emacs: Often switching between Emacs and my IDE's editor, how to automatically 'synch' the files?

Tags: file, emacs, synchronization

I very often need to do some Emacs magic on some files and I need to go back and forth between my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) and Emacs.

When a change is made under Emacs (and after I've saved the file) and I go back to IntelliJ the change appears immediately (if I recall correctly I configured IntelliJ to *"always reload file when a modification is detected on disk"* or something like that). I don't even need to reload: as soon as IntelliJ IDEA gains focus, it instantly reloads the file (and I hence have immediately access to the modifications I made from Emacs).

So far, so very good.

However "the other way round", it doesn't work yet.

Can I configure Emacs so that everytime a file is changed on disk it reloads it?

Or make Emacs, everytime it "gains focus", verify if any file currently opened has been modified on disk?

I know I can start modifying the buffer under Emacs and it shall instantly warn that it has been modified, but I'd rather have it do it immediately (for example if I used my IDE to do some big change, when I come back to Emacs what I see may not be at all anymore what the file contains and it's a bit weird).

Comment: going to sleep so won't upvote/validate before tomorrow : )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(global-auto-revert-mode 1)
```

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: Works flawlessly, thanks a lot... Btw I tried Googling before formulating my question my Google-fu ain't not always strong  : )

Comment: For those who want less of a "blanket" approach - You may want to `(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-revert-mode)` or etc, for whatever modes you use.