# is it possible to use sublime text for building complex java application?

Tags: java, netbeans, sublimetext2

Is it possible to use Sublime text for professional purpose in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely possible, when I first tried to learn java I just used vim and a small ant script, but for enterprise serious development you have to choose one of the big three: [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) , [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

See also :

- [Do developers actually use vim to write code (Java) on a Windows OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827876/do-developers-actually-use-vim-to-write-code-java-on-a-windows-os)
- [Tips for using Vim as a Java IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253170/tips-for-using-vim-as-a-java-ide)
- [Are Vim or Emacs practical for languages like .Net or Java?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61984/are-vim-or-emacs-practical-for-languages-like-net-or-java)
- [Why should I use an IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208193/why-should-i-use-an-ide)

Answer (score 3):

With `ant` build scripts it's definitely possible, and if you don't like the bloat of the IDEs mentioned in the other answers Sublime is a great tool for editing. You can use a combination of [exuberant-ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and the [CTags for Sublime plugin](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags). I haven't used it, but [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) promises [Eclipse-like features for Java](http://eclim.org/features.html#java), and there's an [ST2 plugin called Subclim](https://github.com/JulianEberius/Subclim) that should work for you. Good luck!

---

[The](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16859902/1426065) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16853940/1426065) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16853918/1426065) so far all seem to indicate that an IDE is necessary at some point, and I'm not going to argue that point too far. Java is not my main work language, but some IDEs I've used in the past have the feature of reloading files that have been modified elsewhere, and I would hope that NetBeans has the same feature (I haven't used it in a while). You could set up a workflow where you do much of your regular editing in ST2, but building, major refactoring, etc. could be done in the IDE. It's certainly not an all-or-nothing situation. Use the best tool for the job you're doing now, and try not to get the keyboard shortcuts too confused. BTW, ST2's are completely customizable, as hopefully you're aware...

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it is possible.  Any text editor would be sufficient.  Would I recommend it?  No, stick to an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ for the myriad of features that help you catch errors far earlier than the compilation/run phase.  Not to mention refactoring and introspection tools.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. Theoretically possible, however the reality couldn't be more different...
It's great for JavaScript apps, but for Java you should go with one of the IDEs @tarrsalah listed already.

Answer (score 0):

I use it only doing simple fix on code. We are using svn branches and trunk. and usualy I got eclipse prjects on th trunk. And when I need to fix a problem on a branch I use sublime text